# Dynamic paint on imported objects

Tags: dynamic-paint

I have imported a ship (designed in fusion360) into blender, trying both .3mf format and .obj, both of which do not act as a brush when trying to dynamic paint. A normal cube or isophere works fine just whenever it's an imported object it doesn't do anything.